# gridview can't add after clearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, addition

I am using entity framework and taking my datas from database and fill my gridview with them.Datas selected by user from a treview.Simply, user selects a data from treeview and I put it to gridview. Lastly I have a button for clearing the gridview. Here is my aspx:

```
<div id="divPrint" style="background-color: white" runat="server">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <p style="text-align:center">HDCVI KAMERA FİYAT TEKLİFİDİR</p>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHdcvi" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceHdcvi" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ÜRÜN VE DETAYLARI">
          <ItemStyle Width="400px" />
          <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="color: red" class="text-center"><%#Eval("UrunAdi") %></div>
          <%#Eval("UrunDetay") %>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:ImageField HeaderText="ÜRÜN GÖRSELİ" DataImageUrlField="UrunResim"></asp:ImageField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BİRİM FİYAT">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <%#Eval("UrunFiyati") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ADET">
              <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdet" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
          </ContentTemplate>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
<asp:Button ID="btnListiSifirla" runat="server" Text="Listeyi Sıfırla" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btnListiSifirla_Click" />
```

And my codebehind:

```
 static List<string> urunList = new List<string>();

    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = TreeView1.SelectedValue;
        urunList.Add(id); 
        listeyiDoldur();
    }

    protected void listeyiDoldur() 
    {
        if (urunList.Count == 0)
        {
            failDiv.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            string query = "SELECT UrunTable.UrunAdi, UrunTable.UrunFiyati, UrunTable.UrunResim, UrunTable.UrunKategori, UrunTable.UrunDetay FROM UrunTable WHERE ";
            foreach (var val in urunList)
            {
                if (val.Equals(urunList[urunList.Count - 1]))
                {
                    query += "UrunTable.UrunId = " + val;
                }
                else
                {
                    query += "UrunTable.UrunId = " + val + " || ";
                }
            }
            EntityDataSourceHdcvi.CommandText = query;
            divPrint.Visible = true;
            btnListiSifirla.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void btnListiSifirla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        urunList.Clear();
        btnListiSifirla.Visible = false;
        Page_Load(null,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

I can successfully display selected datas in gridview and clear them when button is pressed. Here is the problem: After clearing the gridview I can't add the last added item again.For example if I add item1,item2 and item3 in this order,after clearing the gridview I can't add item3. I can add item1 or item2, then item3. I can't add item firstly which I added last before clearing. I tried clearing gridview in button's onClick and tried other lots of things but nothing gave any result. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't see where you are clearing the griddata, in the button click `btnListiSifirla_Click` you are just clearing the list and hiding the button itself and calling `Page_Load` explicitly? That's weird, you should not call page load like that.

Comment: I had 'GridViewHdcvi.Columns.Clear();' in onButton click but i deleted it since it didn't solved my problem

Comment: I am not sure why you are clearing the grid items, you can re-bind it right? Your question is not clear to me.